# Solving systems of ordinary differential equations when you can't work out constants from given initial conditions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

Not sure if this is the right place to ask but I am trying to solve systems of ODE's using eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

$$
x'(t) = \begin{bmatrix}5 & 4\\-2 & 1\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}x_1(t)\\x_2(t)\end{bmatrix}, \ \  x_1(0)=0, x_2(0)=1 
$$

I have worked out the eigenvectors and eigenvalues to be $ λ_1 = 3 +2j $ and $ V_1 =  \begin{bmatrix} -1-j \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $ λ_2 = 3 - 2j $ and $ V_2 =  \begin{bmatrix} -1+j \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$

Subbing them into the general formula gives:

$$
x(t)= e^{3t}(d_1(\cos2t\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} -\sin2t\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix})+d_2(\cos2t\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}+\sin2t\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}))
$$

However when trying to work out the values of the d_1 and d_2 I always get an error.

Can anyone help me understand where i've gone wrong, thank you.

Comment: What do you mean that you get an error?

Comment: When trying to find d_1 and d_2, i would try this:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}-1 & -1\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}d_1\\d_2\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$

But that ends up unsolvable. (Unless i'm being super dumb)

Comment: Can you double check that the vectors in the expression of $x(t)$ are all $\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix}$. I don't think that's true. Haven't checked all the algebra, I'm almost sure that the problem lies in the step in which you take the eigenvectors and put them in the last expression.

Comment: Wow you're a genius. That is exactly it, one of them was supposed to be $ \begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\end{bmatrix} $

Feel very stupid right now.

Comment: No problem!  I posted an answer with more details anyway (you may mark that as correct then). good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two eigenvectors $v_\pm = v_1\pm jv_2$ with
$$
v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
v_2 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for eigenvalues $\lambda_\pm = a\pm jb$.
Recall that the general solution to the ode is of the form
$$
x(t) = e^{at}\left(\ \  d_1(v_1\cos(bt) - v_2\sin(bt)) + d_2(v_1\sin(bt) + v_2\cos(bt))\ \ \right)
$$
(see more details in eq (2) [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-iv-first-order-systems/matrix-methods-eigenvalues-and-normal-modes/MIT18_03SCF11_s33_7text.pdf)). Or equivalently
$$x(t) = e^{at}\left(\ \  d_1\left(\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}\cos(bt) - \begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}\sin(bt)\right) + d_2\left(\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}\sin(bt) + \begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}\cos(bt)\right)\ \ \right)$$

Compare this with your result. You basically used $v_1=v_2$